# including foundation using composer

Tags: zurb-foundation, composer-php

I try to learn composer, now I want to include (zurb) foundation, so I added 
"require": {"zurb/foundation": "v5.2.2"} to the composer.json file. 
After running composer.phar update, I can see that there are some files added to the folder /vendor/zurb/foundation.

But I have no clue how to continue, could anybody please advise how I can start building my web-app now? How do I get it to use the css and js files that are needed for foundation?

I already included the file vendor/autoload.php to my index.php, but that doesn't seem to be enough.

I already built multiple web-sites and apps using foundation, but always "manual", then I just include the right css and js files to the header and footer of the page. Now I just don't know where to start.

thanks for your help.

Comment: Composer is for PHP packages. Front-end packages should be included using [Bower](http://bower.io/) (the package manager for font-end packages). You can also take a look at the [component installer](http://robloach.github.io/component-installer/) if you don't want to use bower

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but why is it then available via composer when that doesn't do anything? or am I seeing it wrong?

Comment: because some people thought Composer was the answer to everything... :)

Answer (score 3):

Check this question first to get the basics: [NPM/Bower/Composer - differences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22918517/npm-bower-composer-differences).

---

Then, if you decide to go with Composer for PHP and Bower for front-end libraries, follow this:

1. Install Bower using `sh $ npm install -g bower` (you'll need [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) and [npm](https://npmjs.org/) first)
2. Configure Bower for you front-end packages (visit [Bower docs](http://bower.io/docs/creating-packages/#bowerjson) for more information)

   ```
   {
     "name": "MyProject",
     "dependencies": {
       "foundation": "*"
     }
   }
   ```
3. Hook Bower to Composer adding this to your `composer.json`

   ```
   "scripts": {
     "post-install-cmd": [
       "bower install"
     ],
     "post-update-cmd": [
       "bower install"
     ],
   }
   ```

Now every time you hit `composer update` (or `install`), bower components get updated as well!